# Kubernetes readinessProbe Failed

Tags: kubernetes, devops, readinessprobe, livenessprobe

Pod works normally and internal applications run normally when using only the livenessProbe.

Pod fails when you add with readinessProbe.

Pod runs normally when using only the livenessProbe.
I want to use the readinessProbe with it, but it keeps failing.

**Probe**

```
      livenessProbe:
        httpGet:
           path: /health
           port: 8000
         initialDelaySeconds: 60
         periodSeconds: 5

      readinessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /health
          port: 8000
        initialDelaySeconds: 60
        periodSeconds: 5
```

**Log**

`2023/01/28 06:05:26 failed to connect to server : dial tcp 192.168.241.71:8100: connect: connection refused panic: failed to connect to server : dial tcp 192.168.241.71:8000: connect: connection refused`

Comment: Can you describe the pod and show the events ?
Does the pod takes more time to start and be ready ? Can you try to increase the intialDelaySeconds and try ?